# inputting info from one text box to another with command button

Tags: ms-access

I am new to the world of code and Access, but have been enjoying it so far.  I am currently working in Access.  I am attempting to create a form that allows me to input info into Textbox1 and Textbox2 that are tied to commandbutton1.  Textbox2 will be a file path to an image.  When I select commandbutton1, it displays the information from textbox1 and textbox2 (just file path not image) in textbox3 on the same form with a time stamp.

(time) textbox1 contents/textbox2 contents (just path not image)

Ultimately, I want to have a commandbutton2 on the same form that runs a query for all new records in textbox3 for the last 'n' amount of time which can be selected by the user.  (like 30 mins, 1 hour, 2 hours, etc.)  I think i have that figured out within the criteria section of the query, but I can't seem to crack the nut on the first part.

Final part is that I want to be show the results of that query in a report that shows the contents of textbox1 followed by a "imageviewer" of the textbox2 file path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I keep trying to find threads that would discuss the techniques that I need to utilize, but haven't had an success.  I could just be missing the correct terminology.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Saving concatenated values into textbox3 would simply be like:
`Me.textbox3 = Me.textbox1 & Me.textbox2 & Now()`. If you have the query criteria figured out, exactly what is it you need help with? Use that query as the RecordSource of report. Don't need to 'run' the query, just open report. Textbox on report can reference textbox of open form.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  After reading your instructions, I figured out I need to go another way to get my end goal.  I am trying to do add new record textbox (Event_BOX) to field (TRentry) in reftblTRentry and textbot (Imagepath) to field (Imagepath) in reftblTRentry with 1 command button?

Comment: Also I am trying to display a running log (like a chat window) of all new records as they are added to multiple tables?  Any tips in how I would go about cracking that nut?